# Deserialization causes copies of List-Entries

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'd like to create a very general Model-Layer, which can also be passed arround as JSON. One Model should show a LED-Panel of a RaspberryPi2. Since I'd like to model the Class to be as near as possible to the reality, I force a List to always have 8 * 8 Leds. The Class is looking like this:

```
public class VisualLedPanel
{
    private readonly Lazy<List<VisualLed>> _lazyVisualLeds = new Lazy<List<VisualLed>>(CreateVisualLeds);

    public VisualLed this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            var result = VisualLeds.FirstOrDefault(f => f.X == x && f.Y == y);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<VisualLed> VisualLeds
    {
        get
        {
            return _lazyVisualLeds.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            var tt = value;
        }
    }

    private static List<VisualLed> CreateVisualLeds()
    {
        var result = new List<VisualLed>();
        for (var x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y <= 7; y++)
            {
                result.Add(new VisualLed(x, y));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The problem arises with the Serialization: I'm using the NewtonSoft. Json.Net Serializer, and as far as I've seen, it first accesses the Getter, which causes the Logic to create the Leds, and then sets them afterwards.
The only solution I could think of would either be a Custom-Deserializer or some sort of Constructor shennenigans.
It also seems like the Deserializer doesn't use the Set-Property of the VisualLeds-Value, since my Debugger-Stop never was hitted.

Is there an easy possibility arround to have the best of both worlds? I'd like to have the Model as general as possible without the need of Custom-Deserializer.

Comment: Unless initializing a VisualLed class is really expensive, or there's a path in your code where you're not going to access the VisualLeds property (which seems pretty unlikely, since this class doesn't do anything else), lazy initialization seems like the wrong pattern here.

Comment: Hm, does it hurt? I was under the Impression better Safe than sorry for Concurrency Problems.

Comment: Initializing in the constructor is going to be equally thread safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for you to do this without having to write your own [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) will be to serialize your collection of `VisualLed` objects as a proxy *array* property, marking the original property as [ignored](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm):

```
public class VisualLedPanel
{
    private readonly Lazy<List<VisualLed>> _lazyVisualLeds = new Lazy<List<VisualLed>>(CreateVisualLeds);

    public VisualLed this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            var result = VisualLeds.FirstOrDefault(f => f.X == x && f.Y == y);
            return result;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<VisualLed> VisualLeds
    {
        get
        {
            return _lazyVisualLeds.Value;
        }
    }


    [JsonProperty("VisualLeds")]
    VisualLed [] SerializableVisualLeds
    {
        get
        {
            return VisualLeds.ToArray();

        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
            {
                if (_lazyVisualLeds.IsValueCreated)
                    _lazyVisualLeds.Value.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                _lazyVisualLeds.Value.Clear();
                _lazyVisualLeds.Value.AddRange(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<VisualLed> CreateVisualLeds()
    {
        var result = new List<VisualLed>();
        for (var x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y <= 7; y++)
            {
                result.Add(new VisualLed(x, y));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/glyELu)

For a further discussion, see [Why are all the collections in my POCO are null when deserializing some valid json with the .NET Newtonsoft.Json component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491966/why-are-all-the-collections-in-my-poco-are-null-when-deserializing-some-valid-js).  Using [`ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm) would not be appropriate in this case since you want your `Lazy<List<VisualLed>> _lazyVisualLeds` to be read-only.

Comment: That's a really nice solution, thanks. I will try it asap

Comment: Works like a charm! Like Nick said, it might not even be needed to use Lazy, but I think your example shows exactly, what the intention of the class is. Many thanks.