# Populate object where objects are reused and arrays are replaced?

Tags: c#, json.net

Using Json.NET, I'd like to map a `JObject` onto a .NET object with the following behavior:

1. For (non-null) array properties of the `JObject`, replace the *entire* collection on the target object.
2. For (non-null) object properties of the `JObject`, reuse the target object's property if it's not null, and map just the provided properties onto it.

[JsonSerializer.Populate](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm) seems to be what I want, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30220811/62600). As for the behaviors I'm looking for, it seems I can achieve one or the other, but not both, via [JsonSerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm). `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` does what I want with respect to requirement #1, while `ObjectCreationHandling.Auto` does what I want with respect to requirement #2, but it appends array items onto the existing collection.

What is the recommended way to achieve both requirements here?

Comment: It should be noted that JObject.Merge provides a great way to configure array behavior via [MergeArrayHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_MergeArrayHandling.htm). But this is for JObject-to-JObject mapping, not JObject-to-.NET object. It's unfortunate that this setting isn't available in JsonSerializerSettings.

Answer (score 5):

Json.NET will automatically replace any arrays or read-only collections.  To clear out read-write collections when deserializing, you could create a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) that adds an [`OnDeserializingCallback`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_OnDeserializingCallbacks.htm) to every modifiable collection that clears the collection when deserialization begins.  Clearing the collection rather that replacing it outright handles cases where the collection is get-only, for instance:

```
public class RootObject
{
    readonly HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
    public HashSet<int> HashSetValues { get { return this.hashSet; } }
}
```

The contract resolver is as follows:

```
public class CollectionClearingContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    static void ClearGenericCollectionCallback<T>(object o, StreamingContext c)
    {
        var collection = o as ICollection<T>;
        if (collection == null || collection is Array || collection.IsReadOnly)
            return;
        collection.Clear();
    }

    static SerializationCallback ClearListCallback = (o, c) =>
        {
            var collection = o as IList;
            if (collection == null || collection is Array || collection.IsReadOnly)
                return;
            collection.Clear();
        };

    protected override JsonArrayContract CreateArrayContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);
        if (!objectType.IsArray)
        {
            if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
            {
                contract.OnDeserializingCallbacks.Add(ClearListCallback);
            }
            else if (objectType.GetCollectItemTypes().Count() == 1)
            {
                MethodInfo method = typeof(CollectionClearingContractResolver).GetMethod("ClearGenericCollectionCallback", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
                MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(contract.CollectionItemType);
                contract.OnDeserializingCallbacks.Add((SerializationCallback)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(SerializationCallback), generic));
            }
        }

        return contract;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces());
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetCollectItemTypes(this Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
            {
                yield return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void Populate<T>(this JToken value, T target) where T : class
    {
        value.Populate(target, null);
    }

    public static void Populate<T>(this JToken value, T target, JsonSerializerSettings settings) where T : class
    {
        using (var sr = value.CreateReader())
        {
            JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings).Populate(sr, target);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it, do:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CollectionClearingContractResolver(),
};
jObject.Populate(rootObject, settings);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ma4ABo).

Such a contract resolver would also be useful when deserializing objects that populate collections in their default constructor, as in [Deserialization causes copies of List-Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314523).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Probably has efficiency gains over what I did, albeit the reflection etc. makes for a more complex solution. Sill weighing my options, but thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

One fix is to use a custom `JsonConverter` that effectively replaces collections by ignoring the existing value when a collection type is detected.

```
public class ReplaceArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        // check for Array, IList, etc.
        return objectType.IsCollection(); 
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        // ignore existingValue and just create a new collection
        return JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize(reader, objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
var ser = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Converters = new[] { new ReplaceArrayConverter() }
});

using (var reader = jObj.CreateReader()) {
    ser.Populate(reader, model);
}
```

Comment: Actually all you need to do is to ignore the `existingValue` and return a new collection.

Comment: @dbc I noticed that calling `serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType)` in `ReadJson` gets me in an infinite loop. Pretty easy to see why. Do you think using `JsonSerializer.CreateDefault()` is the right approach there? It works, but not sure if there's something simpler/more efficient.

Comment: That's one of the reasons I suggested using a contract resolver instead.  You could also disable the converter for recursive calls along the lines of `WriteJson()` from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30179162/3744182).  Doing it that way preserves your other serializer settings.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `PopulateObject`, try setting the collection equal to `null`.

Below is an example using a simple C# console app. If you put a breakpoint at the end of the `Main` method, you'll see that the original `Id` property stays the same (since it isn't set in `objectNew`), while the `Name` and `SomeList` properties are updated to new values. You'll also notice that `SomeList` contains 4,5,6 instead of 1,2,3 since it is nulled first before calling `PopulateObject`.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyObject objectOriginal = new()
        {
            Id = 0,
            Name = "Original",
            SomeList = new List<int> { 1,2,3}
        };

        string jsonString = "{\"name\": \"New\",\"someList\": [4,5,6]}";

        MyObject? objectNew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonString);

        if (objectNew?.SomeList != null)
        {
            objectOriginal.SomeList = null;
        }

        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(jsonString, objectOriginal);
    }

}

class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("someList")]
    public List<int>? SomeList { get; set; }

    public MyObject() { }
}
```