# Why does deserialization append to an initialized `List<T>` instead of overwriting it?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a configuration-related data model which is required to have default values for all properties to ensure proper execution of consuming operations. Take for example this very simple model:

```
public class Sample {
    public List<int> Integers { get; set; }
    public Sample() =>
        Integers = new List<int> { 1 };
}
```

This model is expected to contain at least one value so we specify a default processing value based on predefined requirements. However, the value doesn't have to be `1` specifically and if a client specifies a different value or many different values, our process should respect their input. Assume the client specifies the following `json` configuration to be deserialized into the model:

```
{
    "integers": [ 2, 3 ]
}
```

During runtime, we load the configuration directly, but let's use a local `string` variable for the sake of this question:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json
...
string configuration = "{ \"integers\": [ 2, 3 ] }";
var sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample>(configuration);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", sample.Integers));
```

The above code snippet should produce an output of:

> 1,2,3

As you can see in my screenshot below, that is the case:
[image: Screenshot showing the previous code snippets along with an overlay of a console window displaying the aforementioned output.]

However, my question is why... Why does the deserialization process append to the collection instead of overwriting it?

Comment: Well, it respects your code in the constructor. You should know why you initialize the list with values, the serializer does not care about it.

Comment: @SirRufo I'd imagine the serializer would overwrite it by the same logic of not caring. This issue doesn't occur with `string` properties for example.

Comment: *Why does the deserialization process append to the collection instead of overwriting it?*  Because James Newton-King designed it that way.  Json.NET is designed to support populating existing instances via `JsonConvert.PopulaterObject()`, and this is one side effect.  It has been this way for a decade or longer, see e.g. [Dublicate items in list #90](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/90) from 2013 which was closed with the comment *Use ObjectCreationHandling.Replace*.

Comment: If you don't like that there are many workarounds.  Use `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` from Serge's answer.  Use a custom contract resolver or converter that resizes collections before populating them as shown in [Populate object where objects are reused and arrays are replaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42165648/3744182).  But the question of ***why*** James Newton-King chose to do it this way is borderline off-topic for Stack Overflow.  (And in fact he might choose to do it differently after a decade of complaints.)

Comment: @dbc While I'm grateful for your response, and it was very helpful, I'd like to clarify that my question wasn't ***why*** James Newton-King chose to write the deserialization process the way he did, my question was ***why does the deserialization process append to the list instead of overwriting it***, which I believe is on topic for Stack Overflow, very explicitly stated in my post, and has been adequately answered by Serge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point how to deserialize the json

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace};

var sample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sample>(configuration,serializerSettings);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", sample.Integers)); // [2,3]
```

by default it is auto, and if there is something it tries to add.

Comment: Thanks for this! Now I'm curious as to why that's not the default behavior.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Yes, I am agree witn you. But you can email to James Newton-King. He has a profile at this site