# Newtonsoft Json.NET not deserialising getter with null checking

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I've an **ASP.NET Core** *MVC Web API* application. The controller has a POST action which accepts a simple object as shown below:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] SimpleObj o) {
    return await base.Post(o);
}

public class SimpleObj {
    private Record _record;
    public Record Record { get => _record ?? new Record();  set => _record = value; }
}

public class Record {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

If i send a **HTTP POST** request with a **JSON** payload:

```json
{
    "record": {
        "key": "Test1",
        "value": "Passed"
    }
}
```

The received SimpleObj in the controller's **POST** action, I would expect it has its **Record** property be set to `Key = "Test1"`, and `Value = "Passed"`. But I found its **Record** property has been set to **null**!

If I change the code from `get => _record ?? new Record();` to `get => _record;`, **or** if I use `public Record Record { get; set; } = new Record();` instead, then it works fine. I can see the `Record` part in **JSON** has been deserialised properly into the **Record** property which has been set to `Key = "Test1"`, and `Value = "Passed"`!

But the code `get => _record ?? new Record();` means when retrieving the **Record** back if it's null then create an default Record object which should rather affect serialisation not deserialisation, why doesn't Json.NET handle this properly in deserialisation? (*I'm using Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1*)

Comment: I haven't debugged it, but your issue sounds similar (though not identical) to [Why are all the collections in my POCO are null when deserializing some valid json with the .NET Newtonsoft.Json component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32491966).

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331960/10263) for an explanation of what is going on and how to fix it.  The question is a little different, but your code follows the same pattern and has the same problem and possible solutions.