# Why does the Newtonsoft deserializer not deserialize a smart getter?

Tags: c#, json.net

### Context

I have two classes:

- LiteralModel is a wrapper around a string Value property.
- Expression has a string Name and a LiteralModel called Literal.

  ```
  public class ExpressionModel
  {
      private string name;
      public string Name { get => name ?? ""; set => name = value; }

      private LiteralModel literal;
      public LiteralModel Literal
      {
          get => literal ?? new LiteralModel();
          set => literal = value;
      }
  }

  public class LiteralModel 
  {
      private string value;
      public string Value { get => value ?? ""; set => this.value = value; }
  }
  ```

All are public properties with public getters and setters, and so I would expect both of them to serialize and deserialize easily, even with the null guards, and, for the most part, they do.

### The Problem

The Literal property of the ExpressionModel does not deserialize properly. Below is a minimal test that demonstrates the issue:

```
    public void TestNewtonsoftExpressionDeserialization()
    {
        ExpressionModel expression = new ExpressionModel
        {
            Name = "test",
            Literal = new LiteralModel { Value = "61" }
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expression);

        Assert.IsTrue(json.Contains("61")); // passes

        ExpressionModel sut = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpressionModel>(json);

        Assert.AreEqual("test", sut.Name); // passes
        Assert.AreEqual("61", sut.Literal.Value); // fails
    }
```

As you can see, the JSON looks how I want/expect, (wrapping the string "61"), but when I deserialize that back into an ExpressionModel, the Literal test fails--it gets a LiteralModel of an empty string.

### What I've Tried

If I remove the smart-ness of the Literal getter of the expression model, it behaves as expected--all tests pass. But smart properties *do* work on the string properties. So why not on my LiteralModel object?

Even weirder, all tests pass if I move the null-check to the setter instead of the getter like so:

```
        public LiteralModel Literal
        {
            get => literal;
            set => literal = value ?? new LiteralModel();
        }
```

### Conclusion

In short, nothing phases the serializer, and smart setters are fine, but smart getters break deserialization, except for `string`.

This seems like wildly arbitrary behavior. Does anyone know why this might be or if there's any way to get these classes to work as written?

Comment: This is basically the same situation as [Why are all the collections in my POCO are null when deserializing some valid json with the .NET Newtonsoft.Json component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32491966/3744182), and has the same [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32493007/3744182): Json.NET doesn't call the setter after deserialization when the getter returned a non-null value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *suspect* the problem is that Json.NET is calling your property getter, and then calling the setter on the result. For example, something like this - although obviously, via reflection:

```
var expression = new ExpressionModel();
expression.Name = "test";
var literal = expression.Literal;
if (literal is null)
{
    // No literal - create one and set it
    literal = new LiteralModel();
    expression.Literal = literal;
}
// Now literal is non-null either way, so set the value.
literal.Value = "61";
```

With the way your code works, your `Literal` getter is creating a new `LiteralModel`, but then throwing it away. Leaving Json.NET aside, that's still pretty confusing. For example:

```
var expression = new Expression();
expression.Literal.Value = "foo";
Console.WriteLine(expression.Literal.Value); // Empty string
```

You could change your `ExpressionModel` code to assign the newly-created `LiteralModel` to the property if it creates one:

```cs
public LiteralModel Literal
{
    get => literal ?? (literal = new LiteralModel());
    set => literal = value;
}
```

That will avoid the "simple code" behaviour being so confusing - and I *expect* it will fix the Json.NET behaviour too.