# Unable Deserialize the JSON List into List of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, deserialization

I am currently working on a solution that Deserializes the list of email from `json` array, Once I get the list of email objects, I am validating using another class then set into another list.

Below is the code for Deserialize:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jsonTest = "{\"Emails\":[\"testUser@gmail.com\",\"testUser2@gmail.com\"]}";

    Class1 contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(jsonTest);

    Console.WriteLine(contact.Emails[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(contact.Emails[1]);
}
```

And, below is the class definition for `Class1` for deserialize:

```
public class Class1
{
    private readonly List<ValidateEmail> emailsobj;
    public List<string> Emails
    {
        get
        {
            return emailsobj.Select(o => o.EmailAdd).ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (string email in value)
            {
                emailsobj.Add(new ValidateEmail(email));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, below is the `validate` class:

```
public class ValidateEmail
{
    public string EmailAdd { get; set; }
    private bool Valid;

    public ValidateEmail(string value)
    {           
        try
        {
            MailAddress mail = new MailAddress(EmailAdd);
            EmailAdd = value;
            Valid = true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Valid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I deserialize I am getting exception on line :

```
Console.WriteLine(contact.Emails[0]);
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from
>   'Emails' on 'JsonGenerator.Class1'. ---> System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

It looks like the `List<Email>` never set. Any help on this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Plz let know what error you are getting? This line will fail - JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(jsonTest); because the emailsobj is null in class1 and what is MailAddress class?

Comment: Yes You are correct Mahesh. I have received the null reference error message. MailAddress is in-build class which is part of system.net.email. which is used to validate the email.

I just changed to private List<ValidateEmail> emailsobj = new List<ValidateEmail>(). Still failed. Any idea? t would be nice, if you point out my mistake.
The below error raised,

Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'Emails' on 'JsonGenerator.Class1'.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the below setting(Replace) if you are using Lists - [`ObjectCreationHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm).

`Replace` Always create new objects and enables the setter property for the `Lists`!

So after you initialize the new list in `Class1` like below:

```
private readonly List<ValidateEmail> emailsobj = new List<ValidateEmail>();
```

Change the code to have setting:

```
 var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
      {                
         ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace           
      };

 Class1 contact = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1>(jsonTest, settings);
```

See the detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491966/why-are-all-the-collections-in-my-poco-are-null-when-deserializing-some-valid-js) !