# How to inherit from C# generic abstract class in F#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, f#, abstract-class

I have an abstract generic class in C#

```
public abstract class PaymentSystemBase<
    TPayInSettings,
    TPayOutSettings,
    TRefundSettings,
    TCashierContract,
    TPayoutContract
> : IPaymentSystemInitializable, IPaymentSystem

    where TPayInSettings : BasePayInPaymentSystemSettings, new()
    where TPayOutSettings : BasePayOutPaymentSystemSettings, new()
    where TRefundSettings : BaseRefundPaymentSystemSettings, new()
    where TCashierContract : PaymentSystemBaseCashierContract, new()
    where TPayoutContract : PaymentSystemBasePayOutContract, new()
{
..
}
```

Here's my F# code:

```
module Main =
    type CheckoutPaymentIdealUnitTest =
        inherit PaymentSystemBase<
            BasePayInPaymentSystemSettings,
            BasePayOutPaymentSystemSettings,
            BaseRefundPaymentSystemSettings,
            PaymentSystemBaseCashierContract,
            PaymentSystemBasePayOutContract
        > with
        member x = 1
```

IDE throws an error `The type 'PaymentSystemBase<....>' is not an interface type`

Is it possible to inherit from C# generic abstract class in F# and how to do it correctly?

I expect to receive a class similar to that, but in F#:

```
public class PaymentSystem : PaymentSystemBase<
    ..,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    ...
>
{
...
}
```

Comment: Absolutely it is possible for F# types to inherit from C# abstract generic types.  See for example [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74935297/3744182) to [How can I configure NewtonSoft to set a property via the property setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74934702/3744182) and the associated [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T9qvGt) where I define a collection type inheriting from [`public abstract class KeyedCollection<TKey,TItem>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.keyedcollection-2?view=net-7.0).

Comment: So I think we will need to see a [mcve] (as suggested by [ask]) to help you.  It wouldn't surprise me if the specific error message was misleading.  E.g. maybe one of the generic parameters such as `BasePayInPaymentSystemSettings` is also abstract or lacks a parameterless constructor, and so fails the `new()` constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved a problem by creating all needed methods to override

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the primary constructor to define that there is only a default constructor. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/inheritance#constructors-and-inheritance) (see the example just above showing default constructor).

So something like:

```
module Main =
    type CheckoutPaymentIdealUnitTest() =
        inherit PaymentSystemBase<
            BasePayInPaymentSystemSettings,
            BasePayOutPaymentSystemSettings,
            BaseRefundPaymentSystemSettings,
            PaymentSystemBaseCashierContract,
            PaymentSystemBasePayOutContract
        >() with
        member x = 1
```

Comment: New Error: This 'inherit' declaration specifies the inherited type but no arguments. Consider supplying arguments, e.g. 'inherit BaseType(args)'.