# XML Deserialization of Lists

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a Config object which I am serializing into XML so I can load it back again later on. In my configuration object I have a dictionary objects

```
    public Dictionary<int, FooConfiguration> Foos
    {
        get { return foos; }
        set
        {
            if (foos != value)
            {
                foos = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => foos);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I am serializing it doesn't seem to like serializing dictionaries which I can understand, they are complicated objects. So as a workaround I figured I would decorate the property with `[XMLIgnore]` and create a list of my objects which would get the values from the dictionary.

```
    public List<FooConfiguration> FooConfigurations
    {
        get { return Foos.Values.ToList(); }
        set
        {
            int fooNumber = 0;

            foreach (var fooConfiguration in value)
            {
                foos.Add(fooNumber++, fooConfiguration);
            }
        }
    }
```

This worked as far as serializing goes. I could now see these objects in my XML. The problem is, it was never hitting the setter. **Why Would a list be able to serialize but not deserialize?**

I have eventually fixed this by using a `FooConfiguration[]` instead of a list but this seems a bit weird if you ask me.

As you can see I have a solution, I am just really wanting to understand why its doing what it's doing better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to XML-serialize a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671259/how-to-xml-serialize-a-dictionary)

Comment: @JakubJankowski Thanks for that, That is quite an obvious way of serializing a dictionary and pretty similar to my solution. While my main question is about the list not deserializing I do not think it is a duplicate. Maybe i should change the title?

Comment: Use an array `FooConfiguration []` rather than a `List<FooConfiguration>` for your surrogate property.  For an explanation why, see [Cannot deserialize XML into a list using XML Deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179792/cannot-deserialize-xml-into-a-list-using-xml-deserializer/26624551#26624551)

Comment: @dbc Thanks, yeah thats what I ended up doing to get around it. My question was about why the list didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list has a non-null value, it won't *need* to hit the setter; it just calls `Add` on the list it is given. And in your case, the list you are handing it is **detached** from the actual data (becuase you created it in the getter).

So basically, it is deserializing the data into an object that  is left on the floor.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I never thought about this, it's quite obvious when you think about it.

Comment: @Keithin8a the intent, obviously, is to avoid allocating extra lists; but to be fair, this side effect is quite nuanced

Comment: @Keithin8a possible fix: `get { return (Foos == null || Foos.Count == 0) ? null : Foos.Values.ToList(); }`

Comment: Sorry I may be dumb here, but I don't think I understand how that helps the deserialization. Does this force it to use the setter if Foos is null or empty?

Comment: @Keithin8a it it *gets* a `null` instance, it will `new` one up, deserialize, and call `set`... unless, of course, it decides to do it the other way around: `new` one up, call `set`, and then deserialize - in which case you're no better off :(

Comment: Use an array rather than a list for a surrogate property.  The list will be set back immediately after being allocated, while the array will only get set back after being populated.  See [Cannot deserialize XML into a list using XML Deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179792/cannot-deserialize-xml-into-a-list-using-xml-deserializer/26624551#26624551).

Comment: @Keithin8a see dbc's hint above

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for notifying me of this. I really appreciate users going the extra mile. I have actually used an array (see end of question) but I just wanted to know my list property wasn't working which you answered perfectly.