# Conditional XML serialization of list items

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I would like to know if one can conditionally exclude items in a list from being serialized using the `ShouldSerialize*` pattern. For example take the two classes:

```
public class Product{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public List<Styles> ProductSyles {get; set;}
}

public class Styles{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public bool Selected {get; set;}
   public string StyleName {get; set;}
}
```

Can I go about only serializing the items in the `ProductStyles` property with `.Selected = true`? Is this possible using the [`ShouldSerialize*`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pattern

Comment: Make the list private then create a public property that filters the list that before returning results.

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSerializer` has no built-in functionality to omit selected collection entries during serialization.  The quickest way to implement this would be to use a surrogate array property, like so:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Styles> ProductSyles { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("ProductStyles")]
    public Styles [] SerializableProductSyles 
    {
        get
        {
            if (ProductSyles == null)
                return null;
            return ProductSyles.Where(s => s.Selected).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;
            ProductSyles = ProductSyles ?? new List<Styles>();
            ProductSyles.AddRange(value);
        }
    }
}
```

(For an explanation of why a surrogate array should be used in preference to a surrogate `List<Styles>`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26624551/3744182).)