# Exceptions raised running COM DLL

Tags: c#, mfc, com

I will try again .... :)

If I have this code:

```
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonTest()
{
    MSAToolsLibrary::IMSAToolsLibraryInterfacePtr p;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = p.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSAToolsLibrary::MSAToolsLibraryClass));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        __int64 i;
        p->SetPathXML(m_strPublisherDatabaseXML.AllocSysString(), &i);
        p->ReadPublisherData(&i);
    }
}
```

And I run it, I get this silent exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD00B7788 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0x04242420 (parameters: 0x0000000031415927, 0x00007FFCBF6C0000, 0x00000099D88FBDC0).
```

But, if I use a wrapper (header:

```
#pragma once

#import "D:\\My Programs\\2017\\MSAToolsLibrary\\MSAToolsLibrary\\bin\\Release\\MSAToolsLibrary.tlb" raw_interfaces_only named_guids

class CMSATools
{
public:
    CMSATools();
    ~CMSATools();
    void SetPathXML(CString strPath);
    void OpenPublisherDatabase();

private:
    MSAToolsLibrary::IMSAToolsLibraryInterfacePtr m_pInterface;
}
```

Class:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MSATools.h"


CMSATools::CMSATools()
{
    m_pInterface = NULL;

    HRESULT hr;
    hr = m_pInterface.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSAToolsLibrary::MSAToolsLibraryClass));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // TODO: Throw exception ?
    }
}


CMSATools::~CMSATools()
{
}

void CMSATools::SetPathXML(CString strPath)
{
    if (m_pInterface != NULL)
    {
        CComBSTR    bstrText = strPath.AllocSysString();
        __int64     iResult;

        m_pInterface->SetPathXML(bstrText, &iResult);
    }
}

void CMSATools::OpenPublisherDatabase()
{
    __int64 iResult;

    if (m_pInterface != NULL)
        m_pInterface->ReadPublisherData(&iResult);
}
```

And use this in MFC instead:

```
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonGetNames()
{
    CMSATools toolsMSA;

    UpdateData(TRUE);

    toolsMSA.SetPathXML(m_strPublisherDatabaseXML);
    toolsMSA.OpenPublisherDatabase();
}
```

It is doing the same thing, yet I get these silent exceptions:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD00B7788 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0x04242420 (parameters: 0x0000000031415927, 0x00007FFCBF6C0000, 0x00000090F277C040).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD00B7788 in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x00000090F277BB80.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD00B7788 in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD00B7788 in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x00000090F277BB80.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD00B7788 in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD00B7788 in Test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x00000090F277BB80.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCD00B7788 (KernelBase.dll) in Test.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFF80070002, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000, 0x00007FFCBF6C0000).
```

Why should one way work and the other cause exceptions (that I can't seem to even detect)?

### UPDATE

Please hold off - I see my stupid error now! One moment ....

### UPDATE 2

```
void CTestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonTest()
{
    MSAToolsLibrary::IMSAToolsLibraryInterfacePtr p;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = p.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSAToolsLibrary::MSAToolsLibraryClass));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        __int64 i;
        p->SetPathXML(m_strPublisherDatabaseXML.AllocSysString(), &i);
        p->ReadPublisherData(&i);
    }
}
```

I corrected the test case now and they both have the same exceptions raised. This is the method that seems to cause the problem in the DLL:

```
public void ReadPublisherData(out Int64 iResult)
{
    iResult = MakeResult(true);

    try
    {
        _PublisherData.Publishers.Clear(); // Reset

        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_PublisherData.GetType());
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_strPathXML))
        {
            _PublisherData = (PublisherData)x.Deserialize(reader);
            _PublisherData.BuildPublisherDictionaryFromList();
            iResult = _PublisherData.PublisherDictionary.Count;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        iResult = MakeResult(false);
    }
 }
```

As far as I am aware it doesn't cause any exceptions. It seems ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only obvious problem you have is that you don't have a problem.  The COM server you are using was written in a managed language.  Pretty common, dead-simple to do with just an attribute.  Probably C#, given that you've asked questions about it.  The point is that these exceptions are *silent*, they are thrown and caught inside the managed code.

Passing exceptions across a COM boundary is illegal, the CLR gives you a rock-hard guarantee that this will never happen.  If a managed exception is not caught then it gets turned into an HRESULT error code that indicates a failure.  Since you are using the wrappers generated by #import, you'll never actually see these error codes, the wrapper turns them back into a C++ exception by throwing a `_com_error`.  You make no attempt at catching them so if it happens then your program will keel over and die on terminate(), impossible to not notice that.

Fwiw, 0x04242420 is a non-fatal exception code and is an implementation detail of the debugger.  [Documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13726628/17034).

The EEFileLoadException is an unmanaged exception used inside the CLR and triggered when Fusion is asked to load assembly and it can't find it.  Turns into a managed FileLoadException.  You might be slightly more concerned about it given that managed COM servers often have a problem finding dependent assemblies.  But this commonly happens when the managed code uses XML serialization, we know [you are using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482489/failing-to-read-xml-content-using-xmlserializer).  Using exceptions for flow-control isn't very nice but performance is a feature as well.  More about it [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3798614/17034).

So rather best to not fret about it.  If you don't trust your COM server to be implemented correctly then simply debug both.  Project > Properties > Debugging and change the Debugger Type setting from Auto to Mixed.  And use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and tick the checkbox for CLR Exceptions to force the debugger to break when a managed exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.

Comment: I had another question here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/304f1855-f6f0-4b1d-bd3e-09eaad30e50b/calling-a-c-dll-from-mfc-application-properties-missing?forum=csharpgeneral#cd981879-f705-44b7-b531-85ec48045784 But I didn't want to duplicate my question in SO or overload my account.