# Why will the XmlSerializer not deserialize a collection to a delegating property?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Can any one explain to me what is happening here and why one test passes while the other fails?

The only difference between the two `XmlRoots` is the dirrection of the property delegation... Bug? or have i missed something?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Documation.Purchasing.Domain.Configurables.Controls;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace FruitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class FruitTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Fruit_Fail()
        {
            // Fails
            AssertFruitDeserialized<FailingFruitRoot>();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Fruit_Win()
        {
            // Passes
            AssertFruitDeserialized<WinningFruitRoot>();
        }

        private static void AssertFruitDeserialized<TFruitRoot>()
            where TFruitRoot : IFruitCollection
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TFruitRoot));
            var xml =
                @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <fruits>
                    <fruit name=""Apple"" />
                    <fruit name=""Banana"" />
                    <fruit name=""Cherry"" />
                </fruits>";

            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var fruit = (IFruitCollection)ser.Deserialize(stringReader);

                Assert.AreEqual(3, fruit.ListFruits?.Count(), "ListFruits didn't contain the right number of values");
                Assert.AreEqual(3, fruit.Fruits?.Count(), "Fruits didn't contain the right number of values");
            }
        }

        private interface IFruitCollection
        {
            IDictionary<string, Fruit> Fruits { get; }

            List<Fruit> ListFruits { get; }
        }

        [XmlRoot("fruits")]
        public class WinningFruitRoot : IFruitCollection
        {
            [XmlIgnore]
            public IDictionary<string, Fruit> Fruits
            {
                get { return this.ListFruits?.ToDictionary(f => f.Name); }
                set { this.ListFruits = value?.Values.ToList(); }
            }

            [XmlElement("fruit")]
            public List<Fruit> ListFruits { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot("fruits")]
        public class FailingFruitRoot : IFruitCollection
        {
            [XmlIgnore]
            public IDictionary<string, Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("fruit")]
            public List<Fruit> ListFruits
            {
                get { return this.Fruits?.Values.ToList(); }
                set { this.Fruits = value?.ToDictionary(f => f.Name); }
            }
        }

        public class Fruit
        {
            [XmlAttribute("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [C# Can't get my dictionary to serialize in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41471437/3744182).

Comment: Agreed - the work around suggested in your link worked. I feel like it is freeking ridiculous, but it did work...

Comment: Well, I suppose you could use a get-only `ObservableCollection<Fruit>` instead and update the dictionary to changes in the collection.